# Kids below 12 years of age with general ticket in sleeper coach in Indian Rail

Tags: trains, indian-railways, irctc

Can we take a 8-year old child in a rail sleeper coach with a general ticket? If so what extra charges do we need to pay if we do not require extra berth?

Comment: So I am assuming that you have reservation in a sleeper coach but the kid doesn't. Any reason for this? (Is it a late plan change or not your kid or something?)

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since this question is asked but let this answer help someone out who is having the same question.

If you have a general ticket, you might need to pay the difference between general ticket fare from reserved half ticket fare. Let me also remind you that it is not desirable(to be read as **not legal**) to travel without a proper ticket.

**For a child, 5 to 12 years, half of the adult fare is charged even if a berth is not required.**

**If berth is required, the full adult fare is to be paid.**

Source - Press Information Bureau, Government of India

Press release link - http://pib.nic.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid=138458

Comment: I am not sure why that situation in the first place. A family would travel together and have reservations together. Why make a plan to have a general ticket for the kid?

Comment: There may be many situations. Either the parents had planned to travel alone which got changed or the kid might just be a relative.

Answer (score 1):

The Pr. Chief Commercial Managers,
All Zonal Railways

Sub: Fare for children.

Ref: 1. Rule no. 211 of IRCA Coaching Tariff no. 26 Part I (Vol 1).
2. Commercial Circular No. 71 of 2015 dated 02.12.2015.
3. Commercial Circular No, 30 of 2017 dated 24.04,2017.
4. Commercial Circular No, 60 of 201.8 dated 23.10.2018.
5. Board’s letter of even no. dated 09.12.2015.

In continuation of all above instructions issued on child fare, Ministry of Railways have decided to issue consolidated instructions on child fare as under:

Age of Child: Child below 5 years of age
Class of travel: Both reserved and unreserved
Applicable fare: Children under five years of age shall be carried free & purchase of any ticket is not required. However, if berth / seat shall be sought on voluntary basis for children of age below 5 years then ticket shall be issued as under: 1. Full adult fare shall be charged. 2. Divyangjan (children) as per Railway, rule shall be eligible for concession on adult fare.
Age of Child: Children of age 5 years to below 12 years
Class of travel: Reserved accommodation (except sitting) if berth is sought
Applicable fare: In case of children of age 5 years to under 12 years of age for whom full berth (in Reserved class) is sought at the time of reservation, full adult fare for such children shall be charged” (CC 71 of 2015 dated 02.12.2015).
Age of Child: Children of age 5 years to below 12 years
Class of travel: If berth is not sought (NOSB)
Applicable fare: If no berth is opted for., the’ children of age 5 years to under 12 years of age ‘at the time of reservation in such cases only half of the applicable adult fare shall be charged and in this case minimum distance of charge shall not be applicable.” (CC 30 of 2017 dated 24.04.2017).
Age of Child: Children of age 5 years to below 12 years
Class of travel: Reserved sitting accommodation
Applicable fare: In reserved sitting accommodation, full adult fare shall be applicable. “Child NOSB (no seat option) booking shall not be. permitted in CC, EC, 2S, BA etc classes” (CC 60 of 2018 dated 23.10.2018),
Age of Child: Children of age 5 years to below 12 years
Class of travel: Unreserved accommodation
Applicable fare: In unreserved classes, for children of age 5 years to below 12 years’ of age, half of adult fare shall be applicable subject to minimum distance for charge. (CC 71 of 2015 dated 02.12.2015),
Age of Child: Children 12 years & above
Class of travel: All classes
Applicable fare: “Passengers of 12 years and above shall be charged full fare” (Rule 211 of IRCA Coaching Tariff no. 26  Part I Vol(I))
Other conditions:

1. In case of NOSB tickets, tickets for unreserved class etc., for child where half of the adult fare is applicable the same shall be applicable on the basic fare. Other charges like superfast charges, catering charges, GST etc, if applicable shall be levied in full. (Para no. 101 (3) (e) of IRC A coaching Tariff no. 26 Part 1 (Vol II)).
2. Single child or group of children without adult attendant, shall be allowed only in case berths are opted with full fare”. However, tickets for children will be issued with no berth option by linking the PNR of parents / guardians / attendants subject to certain conditions issued vide CC No, 60 of 2018 dated 23.10.2018 which is enclosed at Annexure-I.

Comment: Where did you find this? Can you add a link to the source?

Comment: Formatting this to make it more readable would also help.